# Change subdomain directory to main root

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

my folder structure looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R84hs.png

Im using a shared hosting that allows me to create subdomains but not to change root folders, i need to point that subdomain (api.figurine.ml) to my main domain which is in htdocs, i know that is posible to do it with a .htccess, i already tried to do it but doesn´t work

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/htdocs/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /htdocs/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Maybe im doing something wrong, i would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken .htaccess will redirect visitor relative to current url. You should just symlink your `/htdocs` to `/api.figurine.ml/htdocs`.

P.S.
Don't forget to enable symlinks support in your .htacces. (`Options +FollowSymLinks`)

Comment: RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api.figurine.ml/htdocs/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api.figurine.ml/htdocs/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Do you have SSH access to this hosting?